# Stack buffer overflow: Is compiler changing variables order, preventing me to overwrite EIP properly?

Tags: buffer-overflow, c, x86

I am learning about stack buffer overflow. A little info about my target: A x86 little endian intel-based computer, with a target compiled with TCC Compiler with no protections of any kind running on Windows XP.

I have success when I sent a shellcode of ~15 bytes to attack my own TCP home server. (Designed by myself). The attacked buffer is 20 bytes length.

I have taken precaution to send trash bytes to fill spaces and to override EBP, and attach a hardcoded address reversed to little endian.

But when I sent the same shellcode, but for attack a more bigger buffer above 20-30 bytes, It fails, jumping to a unknown ret addr.

Is compiler changing stack variables order??? I have write first small buffer, and after it a larger buffer. I have changed with a constant proportion the two to be able to fit shellcode.

Is compiler changing order, putting EIP or EBP in another place of stack?? I have disable compiler protections of TCC compiler and siabled system protection such DEP and ASLR.

I can provide more info if it's necessary, including short code fragments, if you ask me for them.

EDIT 1:

Here my target TCP server code in pastebin-like site:

http://tny.cz/57f36e2e

Here my exploit:

http://tny.cz/dc9295ba

EDIT 2:

Can aligment affect my exploit??? I have no many skills in this area. I have choosed values multiply of 4 (32 bits). I think that it could no affect, can somebody clarify me???

EDIT 3: I have discovered than a slighly modified shellcode doesn't work, but a smaller do it. FASM.

THIS NOT WORK:

```
use32

mov eax, 0xDEADBEEF
mov ebx, 0xDEADBEEF
mov ecx, 0xDEADBEEF
mov edx, 0xDEADBEEF
int3
```

THIS WORK:

```
mov eax, 0xDEADBEEF
mov ebx, 0xDEADBEEF
mov ecx, 0xDEADBEEF
int3
```

Why the first, doesn't work??? I have filled remainder space in buffer with trash.
It doesn't look to have null bytes.

Comment: I'm not sure how we can possibly answer your question with the info you have provided.

Comment: @schroeder I am rewriting my question. Please look it.

Comment: You might need to adjust esp before execution your shell code. Try putting a \xCC as the first byte of your shellcode and exectu the exploit with the debugger attached. It should let you validate your shellcode in memory and step through the execution

Comment: Providing pastes of the code you're using for your example server and your exploit would probably be the most helpful thing for us to understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: to wireghoul: Is int3 a char value?? Can it cause me problems?? I have exploiting using strcpy. @JeffFerland Please, look my question again, I have updated it with links to my code in pastebin-like sites.

Comment: @wireghoul I have tried but it doesn't work well. Can aligment cause error?? I have not very skilled in that. I have choosed buffer values multpilies of 4 bytes (32 bits).

Comment: I can't really remotely trouble shoot this. I might have a better idea if you provided some debugger output, are you sure your null bytes aren't causing these issues?

Comment: @wireghoul I have found a little thing: A shellcode short updates and do job, but a larger can't do it. The difference is short. Why that happens??? I am sure that no null bytes are in my second shellcode. Please see updated question.